# Could not load file or assembly "MySQL.ConnectorInstaller"

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017, I'm trying to use the MySQL Web Configuration Tool, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly "MySQL.ConnectorInstaller, 
>   Version=6.10.4.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'  or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have connector/net 6.10.4, MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5, MySql.Data 6.10.4, MqSql.Data.Entity 6.10.4, and MySql.Web 6.10.4 installed.

Can't find where to get MySQL.ConnectorInstaller (dll i presume).

Comment: I have experienced the same problem i still can not find a solution. I suppose problem might have come from the 6.10.4 connector/net version. Can someone give a help?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like 6.10.4 doesn't install the .dlls correctly. I downgraded back to 6.9.10 (via NuGet) and those work fine.